# How best to clarify when wheat beer yeast used

Tags: racking, filtering, clarification, wheat-beer

I innocently/stupidly used a pack of wheat beer yeast (Safbrew WB-06) when making a high hopped light beer (100g Liberty, 100g Cascade, 2.2 lbs of spraymalt and 500g of brewing sugar made up to 20 litres)

The beer tastes exactly what I was going for but is refusing to clarify after several weeks.  I still want to bottle carbonate so was wondering what was best route for clarity (it looks like soup at the moment).  I am happy to rack it into a secondary and/or use finings or go for filtration.  I have heard gelatin can work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time and cold temps are the best way.  Keep it around 35F for a couple weeks and it will clear.

Comment: Hey Denny, since I don't do many beers, would gelatin effect the taste? I know it doesn't for meads and ciders (I've used gelatin on these with no effect other than reduced cloudiness). I hate to suggest something that I don't know from personal experience to be acceptable.

Comment: No, gelatin shouldn't affect it...but I don't have a lot of experience with gelatin.  The couple times I used it I decided it was more hassle than it was worth since I could just leave the beer alone for a while and it would clear on its own.

Comment: Worth racking it so it is off the yeast cake as well?  I've stuck it in the back room where the temp is dropping rapidly due to the weather but I don't think I'll achieve 35F (1.6C) without refrigeration this side of December.

Comment: Waited over a month and no clarification.  Tried racking it as well and left for another week with minimal improvement.  Added a beer fining packet and got amazing results in just over 24 hrs.  Its probably cheating but I have to say the effect was great and as a bonus head retention from the chemical additive is amazing.  Up side is the beer is great tasting now.